# 'ngMessages' not instantiated in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Following is my code

```js
   // LoginCtrl.js

angular.module('homeon', [ 'ngMessages' ]).controller('loginCtrl',
  function($rootScope, $scope, $state, $ionicLoading, dbservices, server) {
  //--------------------------------- my code-------------
})
```

```html
<!-- login.html-->

<link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.4/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- load angular -->
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>

<!-- load ngmessages -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-messages.js"></script>

<!-- load our custom app -->
<script src="js/loginCtrl.js"></script>

<body ng-app="homeon">
 <ion-view view-title="Login">
    <ion-content>
     <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="doLogin(loginForm)" novalidate="">
       <div class="list list-inset">
       <label class="item item-input itemLabel">
          <input type="email" name="username" placeholder="Email" ng-model="username" required="required" ng-minlength="5" >
          </label>
    <label class="item item-input itemLabel">
             <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" required="required" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]).{8,}" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off">
             </label>
    <div ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error" style="color:red; align:center">
     <span ng-message="required">Please enter user name</span>
     <span ng-message="minlength">Length of email must be minimum 5 characters</span>
     <span ng-message="email">Please enter valid email</span>
    <div>
    </div ng-messages="loginForm.password.$error" style="color:red; align:center">
     <span ng-message="required">Please enter password</span>
     <span ng-message="pattern">The passwords must be at least 8 characters and include an
  uppercase, lowercase, number, and special character</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button button-block" ng-click="" >Login</button>
    </div>
   </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
</body>
```

I am getting 'ngMessages' not instantiated error in browser. Can you please let me know where am I doing wrong or why I am getting this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your snipped seems to work fine (beside missing bracket)

Comment: looks like everythink works fine, so what is your problem ?

Comment: its giving me an error in browser as follows

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module homeon due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMessages due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMessages' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `<script src="js/angular-messages.js"></script>` In your index.html page